# Check if a string contains a word?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check if a url starts a certain way. So the proper way to do this would be

```
url.StartsWith("word1/{randomWord}/word2").
```

Is there a way for this to pass with random Word being any number of letters or numbers?

Edit: Any number of letters or numbers*

Comment: `var randomWord = "some randomly generated text"; url.StartsWith($"word1/{randomWord}/word2");`, using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (note the `$` before the opening `"`)

Comment: Sounds like a regex would work best here, assuming the random word is unknown.

Comment: You could use a Regex: `regex.IsMatch(url, @"^word1/[^/]+/word2")`

Comment: So this could be a real headache, as depending on the characters accepted by {randomWord}, you could have hell to pay for, specifically if {randomWord} contains /, ?, & or any other url characters

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant any number of letters

Comment: Could you post some sample input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Regex:

```
regex.IsMatch(url, @"^word1/[A-Za-z0-9]+/word2")
```

- The "^" indicates that this must be at the start of the url
- The "[A-Za-z0-9]" specifies the characters that may be in the random
  word (adapt as required).
- The "+" indicates that the length of the random word must be at
  least 1.

Comment: This isn't the whole url, it only needs to start with that regex

Comment: Yes, therefore there is only a "^" (start of string) and no "$" (end of string anchor) in the regex